# JWT OpenIddict and ASP.Net Core 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, openiddict

When I use Postman to try authentication I get an error. I trace it all the way through and it does the signin and succeeds but then fails returning the ticket.

The DEBUG log is as follows:

```html
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: ASOS
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<SignInAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SignInResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Angular2WebpackVisualStudio.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Configure>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mhorton.NRH\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AngularWebpackVisualStudio-master\src\AngularWebpackVisualStudio\Startup.cs:line 98
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 1950.2099ms 500
```

And here is my Startup.cs. I think the error is in the Startup.cs and I freely admit I don't fully understand it all.

I am authenticating against an ASP.Net Identity Core SQL DB that is accessed via IdentityContext. During the trace the information from this DB is fine, so I am sure that part is working properly. I am intending to use OpenIddict to issue JWT Token using a self signed certificate and I want to use this token in an Angular4 app to access the API on the same server.

```html
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Angular2WebpackVisualStudio.Repositories.Things;
using Angular2WebpackVisualStudio.Models;
using AngularWebpackVisualStudio.DBContexts;
using AngularWebpackVisualStudio.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using AngularWebpackVisualStudio.Shared;

namespace Angular2WebpackVisualStudio
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });
       
            var jwtSigningCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64\SIWWW.pfx", "Test123");
            services.AddOpenIddict()
                .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                .AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<IdentityContext>()
                .EnableTokenEndpoint("/oauth2/token")
                .EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/connect/token")
                .UseJsonWebTokens()
                .AllowPasswordFlow()
                .DisableHttpsRequirement()
                .AddSigningCertificate(jwtSigningCert);

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["DefaultConnection"]);
                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, SqlPasswordHasher>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            var angularRoutes = new[] {
                 "/home",
                 "/about",
                 "/contact",
                 "/login"
             };

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && null != angularRoutes.FirstOrDefault(
                    (ar) => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith(ar, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = new PathString("/");
                }

                await next();
            });

            app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentity();
            app.UseOAuthValidation();
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
            {
                Audience = "414e1927a3884f68abc79f7283837fd1",
                Authority = "localhost:5000",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> When I use Postman to try authentication I get an error. I trace it all the way through and it does the signin and succeeds but then fails returning the ticket.

You must add `app.UseOpenIddict();` after `app.UseIdentity();` (and necessarily before `app.UseMvc();`).

Comment: When I do that I get a 400 Bad Response  

`error:invalid_request
error_description:The mandatory 'client_id' parameter is missing.`  

and if I debug it never reaches the /connect/token Controller

Comment: In your example, `/connect/token` is the address assigned to the authorization endpoint. In this case, `client_is` is a required parameter, as indicated by the error you're seeing. What flow are you trying to use?

Comment: The honest answer is that I am not quite sure what I am doing. Maybe the best thing is if I tell you what I am trying to do then you can help me with what I should be doing.

Comment: I am updating an AngularJS app that used JWT tokens using Owin, Identity and .Net 4.6 to use OpenIddict, JWT, Identity Core and .Net Core.  The API and Authentication are running on the same server. So the tokens I issue are only being used on this server.  
I supply a username and password with a grant_type of password to /connect/token I assumed password flow. The authentication succeeds but the return ticket dies  
As I understand it, authorization should only be used when accessing the API and the supplied ticket is examined for credentials.